# Why AlarmManager doesn't respond

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm confused about this problem I got, when I place this code in `onCreate()` method (to fire after 5 seconds after application is started) it runs good but when I place it inside `onLocationChangeListener()` the code doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                    float[] distance = new float[2];

                    Location.distanceBetween(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), circle.getCenter().latitude, circle.getCenter().longitude, distance);

                    if (distance[0] > circle.getRadius()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Outside, distance from center: " + distance[0] + " meters;" + " radius: " + circle.getRadius() + " meters", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inside, distance from center: " + distance[0] + " meters;" + " radius: " + circle.getRadius() + " meters", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Intent alertIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, MyService.class);
                        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertTime, // alertTime is set for 1000 millis. inside onCreate()
                                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MapsActivity.this, 1, alertIntent,
                                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

                    }
                }
            });
```

I also searched the web but didn't find anything which is about the same as my problem.

EDIT: Here is `MyService.java` class

```
public class MyService extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    createNotification(context, "AAAAAAAA", "ASDFG", "ASDF");
}

public void createNotification(Context context, String msg, String msgText, String msgAlert) {


    PendingIntent notificIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.searchicon)
                    .setContentTitle(msg)
                    .setTicker(msgAlert)
                    .setContentText(msgText);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(notificIntent);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

}}
```

Comment: Check my ans: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297816/starting-service-on-boot-to-to-do-work-every-15-minutes/32298408#32298408

Comment: Sorry but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your alarm is set in the past. Have you planned out the sequence of events that lead to the alarm getting triggered? Here is what currently happens:

1. Activity created
2. Alarm time set to 1 second in the future (from time activity was created).
3. Alarm is only set when location changes.
4. Location changes some time in the future, likely more than 1 second has passed.
5. Alarm is now set for a time in the past.

Comment: Huh actually really good answer, but even if i remove the timer from `onCreate()` doesn't work, but also this leads me to another question which just came to my mind, It is possible to remove the timer and just set when if statement is done `if (distance[0] > circle.getRadius()) ...` to fire the alarm ?

Comment: @StefanRafa I'm not sure what you mean by "even if I remove the timer from ..." I think I've explained exactly why it doesn't work. Perhaps you could provide more details or code showing what you meant. As for your other question, yes - you can do that. But why bother? Why not just directly start the activity instead of using an alarm?

Comment: Can you help me for that, i searched but still cant find anything for my problem.

Comment: @StefanRafa Read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html